# Movie where prisoners with death penalty were forced to participate in a TV show were they could die or win liberty

Tags: story-identification

I particularly remember a guy in an electric chair, with electric wires near his genitals, so that if he gets arousal he could die of electrocution when an almost naked woman would dance in front of him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're thinking of **[Deathrow Gameshow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092859/)**, particularly, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Or-cHdAHNe8) scene (may be considered NSFW)

Comment: I can't vote up, but you've got good Google-fu my friend